# Connect txt elements to the mentioned files in Python

Tags: python

I have a txt with 50 lines - orders. See below for what these stand for.

I want to ask for a directory of the main folder that contains the subfolders that each contain the `ASTIK.shp` in the `ASTIK` subfolder, then the `EAS.shp`, in the `EAS` subfolder then the `ASTOM.shp`, etc

`INT` means to perform an intersection with this code where in this case should involve `ASTIK` and `EAS` shapefiles.

for example the line:

```
INT_ASTIK_EAS  implies:

import geopandas
inte_s=gpd.overlay(ASTIK,EAS,how='intersection')
```

Then go the to the other line and 'catch on' the meaning of the line and perform erase(difference) between the two named shapefiles.

if there is the ER in front of the file names like:

```
ER_ASTOM_ASTIK
```

it should perform:

```
 er=gpd.overlay(ASTOM,ASTIK,how='difference')
```

then finds the exact files and performs it.

Here is the automation of reading the files from the text and performing the actual operation line by line.

```
action_dict = {'INT': 'intersection', 'ER': 'difference'}#associate the 'INT' with the intersection operation and so on
directory=input('Insert dir of the main folder')
with open(input()) as txtfile: #insert directory of txt
    x = txtfile.readlines()
for line in x:
    action, shape1, shape2 = line.split('_')
    print( action, shape1, shape2) # here line is ER_ASTOM_ASTIK or whatever line in the txt file
    if shape1 in sfiles and shape2 in sfiles:
        gpd.overlay(sfiles[shape1], sfiles[shape2], how=action_dict[action])
```

I am thinking of iterating through a main folder and catching these files but is there a better way? How should I do that connection?